# (gedit:15981): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: unig ssh in python

Tags: python, ssh

I'm trying to open gedit from remote PC while I connect using SSH on python,
this is the code that I'm running

```
    import pxssh
import getpass


try:                                                            
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = 'server'
    username = 'user'
    password = 'pass'
    s.login (hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline ('ls')   # run a command
    s.prompt()             # match the prompt
    print s.before          # print everything before the prompt.
    s.sendline ('gedit camera.py')
    s.prompt()
    print s.before


except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
    print "pxssh failed on login."
    print str(e)
```

and I got this error

```
(gedit:17016): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display
```

I know that in normal SSH I must use 'SSH -X user@server'
but here in python I don't know how I do it !!!
please help

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is achieved by ssh creating a tunnel from the remote machine on a suitable port (typically 6010 which is X11 display 10) and setting the DISPLAY environment variable to match (ie: DISPLAY=localhost:10.0). The [pxssh](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pxssh.html) package does not appear to have support for tunnels so will not be handling X11 remoting.

Comment: thanks @patthoyts for your answer.
I appreciate if you have any idea to help me with this problem